# Hilbert 90 for higher K-groups

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

For a field $F$, Let $K_n(F)$ be the Quillen's $n$-th K-group of $F$.Then $K_0(F)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, $K_1(F)\cong F^\times$.

For a finite Galois extension $L/K$, $K_n(L)$ are Galois modules.
Then $\mathrm{H}^1(L/K,K_0(L))=0$ trivially holds, and $\mathrm{H}^1(L/K,K_1(L))=0$ by Hilbert 90.

In Srinivas's book Algebraic K-Theory, Page 161, it is proved there if $L/K$ is a cyclic extension, then $\mathrm{H}^1(L/K,K_2(L))=0$.

For general Galois extension $L/K$, do we have $\mathrm{H}^1(L/K,K_2(L))=0$?

Do we have more Hilbert 90 style results on higher K-groups?

Comment: A simple computation shows that Hilbert 90 holds for the (Quillen) K-theory of finite fields. Does it hold for the K-theory of $\mathbb{C}$ endowed with complex conjugation?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: the K-theory of $\mathbb{C}$ can be decomposed into Milnor K-theory and some uniquely divisible stuff. So the inclusion of Milnor K-theory into Quillen K-theory should induce an isomorphism in group cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acting by complex conjugation. I think this implies that Hilbert 90 holds in this situation.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt I thought that $K_n^M(\mathbb{C})$ is uniquely divisible for $n \geq 2$ and that $K_n(\mathbb{C})$ has torsion $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ for odd $n$ (at least this is what I understood from the K-book, see especially VI.1.7.1 and the table VI.3.1). If complex conjugation acts trivially on the torsion then I think we get non-trivialilty of $H^1(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},K_*(\mathbb{C}))$.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: of course, you're right. Sorry, I was being stupid. In $K_3$, the torsion is in the indecomposable part. I'm not sure about the action of complex conjugation. I always think of the torsion as coming from roots of unity (in $K_3$ this is more clearly visible). On the roots of unity the complex conjugation wouldn't be trivial, only trivial on $\pm 1$. I'll have to think about the action, but this could be a potential source of counterexample...

Comment: @MatthiasWendt According to VI.1.7.1 in the K-book, complex conjugation acts trivially on $K_3(\mathbb{C})_{\mathrm{tors}}$ so that $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}),K_3(\mathbb{C})) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and similarly for $K_{4i-1}(\mathbb{C})$, $i \geq 1$. This seems to answer the question, but I admit I would be more satisfied with a more concrete description of this 2-torsion element in $K_3(\mathbb{C})$. For example, does it come from the Bloch group of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Note that Hilbert 90 also makes sense for the Bloch group and more generally for Goncharov complexes.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: the Bloch group is uniquely divisible for algebraically closed fields. The torsion in indecomposable $K_3$ comes from a term $Tor(\mu(F),\mu(F))^~$, an extension of a Tor of the roots of unity $\mu(F)$ with itself (as abelian groups). A detailed discussion of the computation of $K_3$ of fields can be found in Section 3.2 of Knudson's "Homology of linear groups" (or in Suslin's papers on the subject). I think an explicit description could be extracted from there.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: Definitely the Hilbert 90 question for Goncharov complexes would be interesting. But the complexes in Goncharov's papers are usually defined with rational coefficients (and this is used in some of the arguments). At this point, I am not sure if the obvious integral versions of Goncharov's complexes are right for all applications. Maybe complexes built out of the rank filtration for group homology of $GL_n$ are better for integral/torsion questions.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt Thanks for the references. I see, then maybe a better question is to look at motivic cohomology $H^i(\mathrm{Spec} k,\mathbb{Z}(j))$. But since this is related to the Bloch-Kato conjecture this might be very difficult...

Answer (score 2):

Another good reference is Weibel's [K-book](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook.html), see section III.6. Voevodsky has proved that Hilbert 90 indeed generalizes to higher Milnor K-theory, see III.7.8.4 in the K-book.

Comment: Note that there is an important difference between Milnor K-theory and K-theory.